# set CURLOPT_INTERFACE for ip class

Tags: class, curl, ip, bind

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE,'86.120.142.100');`

was working fine, but hosting provider changed the rules

How do i bind to whole ip class : `86.128.142.0/24`  ?

It does not work: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE,'86.128.142.0/24');`

Thanks